# CocoaAsyncSocket Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: tcp, network-programming, tcpclient, asyncsocket, cocoaasyncsocket

I need to receive TCP packets using CocoaAsyncSocket. When I'm importing that library to Xcode and trying to run my application, it gives me Apple Mach-O Linker Errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_kCFStreamErrorDomainMach", referenced from:
  -[AsyncSocket errorFromCFStreamError:] in AsyncSocket.o
"_kCFStreamErrorDomainNetDB", referenced from:
  -[AsyncSocket errorFromCFStreamError:] in AsyncSocket.o
"_kCFStreamErrorDomainNetServices", referenced from:
  -[AsyncSocket errorFromCFStreamError:] in AsyncSocket.o
"_kCFStreamErrorDomainSystemConfiguration", referenced from:
  -[AsyncSocket errorFromCFStreamError:] in AsyncSocket.o
"_kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings", referenced from:
  -[AsyncSocket maybeStartTLS] in AsyncSocket.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So, What Can I do???

Comment: ... link the right library/framework?  Where do those constants come from?

Comment: I tried, Doesn't Work.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add SecurityFramework in the Frameworks. 
I also met this similar problem.